# How to solve linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in Xcode 10

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm working with Xcode 10 and I get this error when I build or run:

```
framework not found FirebaseNanoPB
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and of course, I'm openning `.xcworkspace` file!

Here's what I've tried

- deleted `Podfile Podfile.lock` `Pods` and run `pod deintegrate`, then run `pod install`
- carthage update, build
- Clean and rebuild
- set the `Build Active Architecture Only` to NO

these didn't help me... Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've solved it with following steps.

- Delete the corresponding framework(s) (in my case `FirebaseNanoPB`) from the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`
- Clean the project (maybe unnecessary)
- run `pod update && pod install`

I think in my case not doing the first step and `pod update` is the cause for this.